# C struct stat info not updating in a loop, giving ridiculous modification date

Tags: c, file, directory, stat

For one part of a code, I need to save both the name and the stats (user ID, group ID, modification time, permissions, etc.) of every file in a given directory into an array of self-defined structs. The saving info into the array is fine, so for clarity, I left those things out. The problem I'm having is with the pre-defined `struct stat`: in testing, it prints out the same exact modification date for every file in the directory, which is one problem, and the date is from 1969, which is another problem (considering I clearly remember creating and modifying those files sometime last year). I'm not sure what's going wrong; some help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is my very first time coding in C, so if there are any blatant errors, please do let me know. My professor is very big on independent research and doesn't exactly cover all the important things to know. Also, I'm aware that I need to be checking for errors -- those checks have been written and will be implemented later. I just need to fix the sunny-day portion of this code before I worry about all of my error checks, so please don't tell me that that's my problem. I'm always handing it a plain ol' readable directory. It should have no trouble opening or reading.

```
  int main ()
  {
        DIR *myDIR;
        struct dirent *mydirent = malloc(sizeof(struct dirent));        //necessary?
        struct stat mystat;
        myDIR = opendir(pathname);
        int count = 0;
        while ((mydirent = readdir(myDIR)) != NULL)
             count++;
        rewinddir(myDIR);
        struct file_info **file_info_array = malloc(sizeof(struct file_info*)*(count+1));
        int i = 0;
        while ((mydirent = readdir(myDIR)) != NULL)
        {
             stat(mydirent->d_name, &mystat);
             printf("name: %s\n", mydirent->d_name);
             printf("mod_time: %s\n", ctime(&mystat.st_mtime));

             /*
             ... saving file info into file_info_array
             */

        }
        int is_closed = closedir(myDIR);

        /*
        ... freeing pointers
        */

        return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: You aren't checking whether `stat()` succeeds; you can't defer error checking — it isn't sane/safe.  If it fails, there's no guarantee that the contents of the stat structure are sensible.  And you haven't shown how `pathname` is set.  If `pathname` is not `.`, then the `stat()` calls _will_ fail; you need to convert the name returned by `readdir()` into a name relative to `pathname` (roughly `pathname + mydirent->d_name`).  Etc.

Comment: Oh, goodness, that's why! It needs to be a full path? That makes sense, but for some reason when other classmates coded it, they implemented it the way I originally did, as just `mydirent->d_name`, and had no problems. I wonder why.

Comment: Not necessarily a full path; just a path that can be found.  If you simply do `stat(mydirent->d_name, …)`, you're looking for a file with the given name in the current directory — not the directory the name was read from (unless that directory happens to be `.`).  Maybe classmates used `chdir(pathname)`?

Comment: So then how come it successfully prints out all the names, even though they only exist in the inputted directory and not my current one? I'm not trying to argue with you; I'm just genuinely curious as to how stat and dirent actually work lol.

Comment: @jiccan, on a side note, no, it isn't necessary to `malloc()` space for a `struct dirent` just because you declare a variable that can point to such.  You *do* need to assign a valid value to the variable before you can safely dereference it, but you do so by assigning the return value of `readdir()`, supposing that `readdir()` succeeds.  And when you do that in your current code, you leak the memory you allocated.

Comment: The `readdir()` reads the name (only; no path information) from the directory named by `pathname`. So it can be printed.  The `stat()` fails, in general, so you get garbage to print for the information from it.

Comment: As John Bollinger says, the `malloc()` is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

You aren't checking whether `stat()` succeeds; you can't defer error checking — it isn't sane/safe. If it fails, there's no guarantee that the contents of the `stat` structure are sensible. And you haven't shown how `pathname` is set. If pathname is not `.` (or a synonym for `.`), then the `stat()` calls *will* fail; you need to convert the name returned by `readdir()` into a name relative to `pathname` — for example:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];    /* <limits.h> - if it is defined at all */
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", pathname, mydirent->d_name);
if (stat(path, &mystat) == 0)
{
    …go ahead with printing, etc…
}
```

> Oh, goodness, that's why! It needs to be a full path? That makes sense, but for some reason when other classmates coded it, they implemented it the way I originally did, as just `mydirent->d_name`, and had no problems. I wonder why?

Not necessarily a full path; just a path that can be found. If you simply do `stat(mydirent->d_name, &mystat)`, you're looking for a file with the given name in the current directory — not the directory the name was read from (unless that directory happens to be `.`). Maybe classmates used `chdir(pathname)`?  Or maybe they only used `.` (or a synonym for `.`) as the path name?

> So then how come it successfully prints out all the names, even though they only exist in the inputted directory and not my current one? I'm not trying to argue with you; I'm just genuinely curious as to how `stat()` and `dirent` actually work.

The `readdir()` reads the name (only; no path information) from the directory named by `pathname`. So it can be printed. The `stat()` fails, in general, so you get garbage to print for the information from it.

[John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545934/c-struct-stat-info-not-updating-in-a-loop-giving-ridiculous-modification-date?noredirect=1#comment52948815_32545934):

> On a side note, no, it isn't necessary to malloc() space for a struct dirent just because you declare a variable that can point to such. You do need to assign a valid value to the variable before you can safely dereference it, but you do so by assigning the return value of readdir(), supposing that readdir() succeeds. –

As John Bollinger says, the `malloc()` is unnecessary, and worse, it is a memory leak.

Comment: Wonderful, wonderful. Thank you. But I do need to allocate memory both for my pointer to an array of pointers to self-made structs, right? As well as for each individual pointer to said struct? Then, at the end of the code, free each struct pointer before freeing the overall array pointer? Also, how do I go about checking that `opendir()`, `readdir()`,  `rewinddir()`, and  `closedir()` were successful? Is it essential to check each of those?

Comment: You check `opendir()` returns a non-null pointer.  You're already checking that `readdir()` returns a non-null pointer.  The structure allocated by `opendir()` is released by `closedir()`; there is no other way to do it.  The structure allocated by `readdir()` is managed by `readdir()` and may not be released by you.  The value returned may only be used until the next call to `readdir()` on the same directory stream, or until `closedir()` on the directory stream.  Unless you explicitly allocate some memory, there is nothing for you to free.

Comment: MORE IMPORTANT QUESTION: Do I have to allocate memory for regular `char *` strings? I know that string addition doesn't work in C (though it works so wonderfully in C++). I'm assuming I'll have to make a new `char *`, allocate enough memory to hold the pathname plus the filename, and then use `strcat()`. I just wish there was a shorter, more direct way of doing this.

Comment: I showed you how to do that in the answer — with a minor (unstated) caveat about with PATH_MAX exists as a macro in `<limits.h>`.  You can create a character array as long as the longest path and format into that — as shown with `snprintf()`.  Or you can allocate the memory.  If you have [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), use it.  And free what it allocates for you at an appropriate time.

Comment: Welp, now I'm getting a seg fault. UPDATE: Just kidding, I had the snprintf outside of the loop so it had no directory entry to look at. THANK YOU MUCH!!!!

Comment: OK; there are lots of possible reasons for that, but most likely you're accessing a null pointer somewhere along the line.  It'll be hard to debug without having your code.  Add it to the question — do not destroy the original code.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  I wouldn't have guessed that was the problem.